# QHeaderView: Stretch or ResizeToContents based on columns' content size

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5, qheaderview

I have a QTableWidget with a last column that contains text of variable length.

I want to either stretch or resize the last section of the QHeaderView to its contents based on the size of the section. If the content size does not exceed the remaining space in the widget, I want to stretch it (to prevent an ugly, unfilled space in the widget). I can achieve this by using `setStretchLastSection(True)`. However, if the content size exceeds the stretched column, the last parts of my contents are cut, as the column is not resized. QHeaderView provides the `ResizeToContents` ResizeMode for this case, but this leaves the widget with unfilled space in the case of short contents.

I thought about manually resizing the column size. Unfortunately, I cannot access the content size directly, as `sectionSizeFromContents()` is protected. I guess I could subclass QHeaderView and reimplement it, but I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Protected methods are accessible in pyqt, If you're not using python, please remove the pyqt tags from your question.

Comment: I am using pyqt5. When trying to call `sectionSizeFromContents()`, I get the following Exception: `RuntimeError: no access to protected functions or signals for objects not created from Python`.

Comment: Yes, just create an instance of `QHeaderView` and set it on the table. There's no need to create a subclass.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that this makes a difference. I could indeed access the method by creating an instance myself. However, I misunderstood the functionality of `sectionSizeFromContents()`, but could solve my problem using other functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I misunderstood the functionality of `QHeaderView::sectionSizeFromContents()`. I assumed that it returns the section size of the cells belonging to the section, but this information can of course not be stored in the header. Instead, it returns the size of the header content, i.e. the given label.

However, it is possible to get a column's content size by `QTableWidget::sizeHintForColumn()`. My table has only two columns, so to compute the remaining space for the second column I can use:

```
stretched_size = table.viewport().size().width() - table.horizontalHeader().sectionSize(0)
```

which equals the column size in the `ResizeMode::Stretch`. I can therefore solve my problem by setting the section size to the maximum of the stretched size and the column's size hint:

```
size = max(table.sizeHintForColumn(1), stretched_size)
table.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(1, size)
```